# bias when not using a development set

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing a small classification task in Weka using 10-fold cross-validation. For feature selection and adjusting the parameters of the classifier I used a small subset of my data. I know normally a train and development set should be used.But due to lack of time and computational power, I just used a small subset of all data. Would this in any way bias the results? Thanks!

Comment: Probably more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com, and you'll need to elaborate on your data, etc. In general, yes this will induce a bias, but it still might be a good idea if you are constrained by computing capabilities and/or available data.

Comment: @EMS thanks!I'll ask my question there! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By the very definition of bias, using a small set means you will have a higher bias, towards whatever section you decide to train on. If you randomly choose small samples from a larger data set though, this bias will be greatly minimized.

If you're just using a small set of data, 10-fold cross-validation doesn't make much sense. The idea of cross validation is to chunk up a large data set into multiple parts, training with alternating parts of them serving as train and test sets, iterating until the best solution across all cross-validation sets is found.

If you don't have much time or computational power my first suggest would be to step down your 10-fold CV checking. This will mean you can include a much larger portion of your data set for the same computation time and quickly evaluate a number of different models in Weka before deciding which has the more promise to move forward with.

If you have the option, for your final data run I would **highly** suggest using the full set, but while you're deciding which algorithm to use it's not terrible to use a portion of your full set.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it's better to test on a larger piece of the data as to avoid overfitting. But do I still run 10-fold CV?

Comment: Ideally yes, on the full data set you would still cross validate. If you want, you can probably take it down to a lower number like 3 or 5 folds though.